# Logitech MX Master kills (destroys) bluetooth on my laptop

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, logitech-mouse, wireless-mouse

I (last night) upgraded to an MX Master.

I have 1 major problem.

When I use bluetooth, the mouse works then after a while (seems to be triggered when it goes into the Logitech Options software), it stops responding. Not only that but all my bluetooth is kaput. The first time it happened bluetooth didn't show up anymore in my windows settings.

I have an Intel wifi card for laptop, that AC one. Not sure the model #. The only way to resurrect bluetooth (so that my bluetooth speakers and stuff will work again - as well as the mouse), is to reinstall / upgrade the Intel drivers. A simple restart doesn't help.

This happened twice then I switched to the unifying receiver. Now that works fine, but I lose a usb port.

The mouse was new but battery level was "good"

Would anyone have an idea what causes this? How can 1 bluetooth device cause so much devastation?

Comment: Was this problem ever solved?

Comment: I wish... someone else wrote a comment here a week or 2 ago with the exact same problem but I can't see it anymore.. maybe he fixed his problem? If you come across anything, please update it here... I just gave up after posting, and used the unifying receiver - but bluetooth would be nice to use

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happens to me and has on multiple computers.
Here's my experience.  When the Mix Master bluetooth mouse battery is low it kills the computer's bluetooth.
The fix is to shut down computer, re-start and go into the bios settings (on my Dell computer, tap F2 while the machine is re-starting / before the Dell logo appears).
Navigate to "wireless" and expand.  See that the Bluetooth is now checked.  Exit and start computer as normal.
This has happened to me 4 times now.  I've had this mouse for 3 years.